# VirtualBox Centos7 machine has no IP address when host is connected on WiFi instead of LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, centos

So I have a CentOS 7 (minimal inst) VM on VirtualBox with **Bridged Adapter** network configuration, on my laptop (host). Whenever I have my laptop (host) connected on **WiFi**, there is **no IP** address assigned in the network interface of my CentOS VM (guest). When I plug my laptop (host) **via a cable** into my router then I **get assigned an IP** address on my CentOS VM (guest). I should note that when on WiFi, my laptop (host) **has an IP** address and also internet connection.

Is it even possible to get an IP address on the VM (guest) when my laptop (host) is connected to WiFi?

Thank you

**EDIT:** 
As @Didier suggested the fix lies in the network configuration. To be more precise:

> Settings -> Network -> Name

And chose the name of the adapter you want your VM to connect to (or in this case "bridge to"). For me the name was "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless", it can be different in other laptop models/brands.

Comment: did you resolve the issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363003/no-internet-connection-on-virtualbox-windows-7-as-guest-ubuntu-13-04-as-host) by @jakesantos seems to have solved the OP's problem.

> 1. Open **Virtualbox Manager**
> 2. Select the machine you cannot get internet on in the left pane
> 3. Click the **Settings** button in the top menu
> 4. Click **Network** in the left pane in the settings window
> 5. Switched to **Bridged Adapter** in the **Attached to** drop-down menu
> 6. Select the name of the network adapter you are currently using on your host machine. I am using wireless so I chose *eth0* which is my
>      wireless network adapter. You can check which adapter you are
>      currently using by opening the terminal
>      (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by default) and running
>      `ifconfig`. It will probably be the *eth* adapter that shows an *inet
>      addr* and shows data transfer next to *RX bytes*.
> 7. Under **Advanced**, make sure the machine is using the **Desktop Adapter Type**
> 8. Under **Advanced**, make sure **Promiscuous Mode** is set to **Allow VMs**
> 9. Under **Advanced**, make sure **Cable connected** is checked on
> 10. Hit **OK** to save your changes
> 11. Start your VM
>
> This is an image showing an example of the settings you need (taken
>   from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/248308/134632) answer).
>
> [image: Virtualbox Network Settings]